# Filling datatable with int array.

Tags: c#, arrays, database

I have this array of integers

```
int[] arr = [2,3,54,6];
```

I have this dataTable:

```
var myDataTable = new DataTable();
```

How can I fill myDataTable  with arr?

Comment: Is that a single row or one row for each int? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Numbers", typeof(int));
foreach(int num in arr)
{
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(num);
}
```

this will add a column and populate it with the numbers, for multiple columns your row insert would instead be `myDataTable.Rows.Add(num, secondCol, thirdCol, etc...);`

If you want to clear the data before each insert, you can also call `myDataTable.Clear();` before inserting anything

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
foreach(int num in arr)
{
   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Column1"] = num;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: and where is the array?

Answer (score 0):

with "using System.Linq" try this

```
        int[] arr = { 2, 3, 54, 6 };
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        arr.ToList().ForEach(x => dt.Rows.Add(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
int[] arr = { 2, 3, 54, 6 };
DataTable dt = new DataTable("myDataTable");
dt.Columns.Add("myValues");
foreach (var x in arr) { dt.Rows.Add(x); }
```